# What to do after setting include path in php.ini?

Tags: php

Please enlighten me on this one. I tried editing the php.ini file, on the part where it says include_path:

```
include_path = ".;C:\php_includes\home_made"
```

After that I uncommented it,save it and restarted all services from wamp tray icon.

I have a bunch of home made classes on that folder. I'm imagining that I could just do something like this on every php file that I make. And I'll be able to use the functions in those classes:

```
$strings = new strings();
echo $strings->clean('bla$#@D232)*/');
```

But I was wrong since it returned this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'strings' not found in C:\wamp\www\dw_fs\phpinfo.php on line 1
```

What benefit did I actually get from including a path in php.ini. How do I use it? Please enlighten me.

Comment: try `require_once('strings.class.php');` without any paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include_path just allows to [`include`](http://php.net/include) files without full path:

```
include("strings.php");   // instead of "c:/includes/strings.php"
```

What you wanted to use in your example is an [`autoloader`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) in addition to setting the `include_path`:

```
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register("spl_autoload");
```

Then you can instantiate the strings class without manually including the required class file.

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to include files using include() and require() without having to specify the full path.

From the manual : http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

> Specifies a list of directories where
>   the require(), include(), fopen(),
>   file(), readfile() and
>   file_get_contents() functions look for
>   files. The format is like the system's
>   PATH environment variable: a list of
>   directories separated with a colon in
>   Unix or semicolon in Windows.
>
> PHP considers each entry in the
>   include path separately when looking
>   for files to include. It will check
>   the first path, and if it doesn't find
>   it, check the next path, until it
>   either locates the included file or
>   returns with a warning or an error.
>   You may modify or set your include
>   path at runtime using
>   set_include_path().

Answer (score 2):

You still need to include your `string` class. Just calling it won't work - but if the file is in the include path then you don't actually need to specify the full path to the file.

If you want to get PHP to auto include the files for you, read up on [Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `strings` class?

The string class is `String`.